# Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I am trying to import 'PopupModule' Module from 'ng2-opd-popup' to my app.
Webpack compiles fine, but I get this error in the browser and nothing loads:

[Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1109.png)

In App.module.ts file i am trying to add:

```
import { PopupModule } from 'ng2-opd-popup'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [
    PopupModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If i remove this module then everything works fine.

I am using angular 4.

**Versions**:

- @angular/cli: 1.4.5
- node: 6.9.1
- os: win32 x64
- @angular/common: 4.4.6
- @angular/compiler: 4.4.6
- @angular/core: 4.4.6
- @angular/cli: 1.4.5
- @angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
- typescript: 2.3.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**I have also face this issue , I have tried to work with downgraded option but still I was not able to work in shared module .**

**I have install other package and it works**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-modal

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... currently i am using ngx-bootstrap-modal instead of      opd popup but facing an issue with this one as well... I am not able to bind title and messages from the component ... when i fix all message in the html then it works fine ... I need to update message from the component

Comment: Does ng2-modal support the latest versions of angular... I am working with 4/5 ...

Comment: I am using it with angular4.x.x

Answer (score 0):

Go to inside your `ng2-opd-popup` folder in node-modules folder and delete the node_modules folder inside there (inside `ng2-opd-popup` folder). It is not needed. I have also faced this issue and so it worked without the folder.